# Как получить данные в табличной форме из колонки с JSON объектом?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql, преобразование

Есть таблица с JSON объектом в одной из колонок:

```
create table jsondoc (id int, doc clob check (doc is json));

insert into jsondoc
select 1, '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}' from dual;
```

Как можно получить данные из этой колонки в табличной форме?

Ожидаю получить:

```
KEYS     VALUES
-----    -------
key_1    value_1
key_2    value_2
...      ...
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to convert json to columns and rows with SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67469809/6571020) от участника [@Menja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10465754/menja)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67469809

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться [PL/SQL Object Types for JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/pl-sql-object-types-for-json.html#GUID-C0C2A8C0-99BD-4770-9EA2-B7D53804FC18), они довольно просты в применении.

Воспроизводимый [пример](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=141c8b230e646465173d857e853d3a57):

```
create or replace package pack as 
    type pair is record (key varchar2(8), value varchar2(16));
    type pairtab is table of pair;
    function getpairs return pairtab pipelined;
end;
/
create or replace package body pack as 
    function getpairs return pairtab pipelined is
        doc clob;
        obj json_object_t;
        keys json_key_list;
    begin
        select doc into doc from jsondoc;
        obj := json_object_t (doc);
        keys := obj.get_keys;
        for i in 1..keys.count loop
            pipe row (pair (keys(i), obj.get_string (keys(i))));
        end loop;
        return;
    end;
end;
/
```

Сам запрос и результат:

```
select * from pack.getpairs()
/
KEY      VALUE           
-------- ----------------
key1     value1          
key2     value2          
key3     value3
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67540788) от участника [@0xdb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6571020/0xdb)</sub>